# Why was this question about executing my compiled code off topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I posed [this question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663480/how-can-i-get-stdio-output-when-running-application-as-root) and it got closed. It was basically about no output ob terminal when running my program.

I searched around and found other questions closely related questions. There were quite a few not closed questions about executing programs, too, as outlined in this comment below:

> @CaptainObvlious some other related ones: stackoverflow.com/questions/15080835/… stackoverflow.com/questions/10467031/at-command-is-not-executed stackoverflow.com/questions/9812145/… stackoverflow.com/questions/14625580/… and they aren't closed. –  Annonomus Penguin 3 hours ago

It's one thing to have these types of questions on topic, but I'm not all that sure where to draw the line. Should the others be closed? Was my question just not worded right (and I edited too late with too little clarification)? I need to run this as root to utilize one of my libraries I have.

I flagged the question to be migrated, but I'm still not that sure that this is totally off topic as it is in the gray area along with Git and other tools like text editors.

Comment: It was closed because it's not a programming question. It's about configuring your system. There could be any number of reasons why your program is not outputting anything, which a system administrator is more likely to be familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't think that your question and the linked questions are representative of each other.

[Difference between ./executable and . executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625580/difference-between-executable-and-executable) is asking about the "source" command in bash. The fact that the name of the executable shares the same with your example is completely irrelevant.

[Linux, how to execute an executable / non-executable file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812145/linux-how-to-execute-an-executable-non-executable-file) again is asking about the source command.

[at command is not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467031/at-command-is-not-executed) doesn't have anything to do with your question.

[Running an executable in Mac Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080835/running-an-executable-in-mac-terminal) is about Mac OSX. You're on Linux. It also doesn't refer to sudo.

While questions that relate to tools used directly for programming are on-topic, your question is not about either shells or GCC. It's about the behavior of "sudo", which means that for any number of unknown reasons, your system is configured incorrectly. Somebody who is familiar with Linux systems (i.e., a system administrator) is more likely to be able to debug your issue than a programmer. Would you ask a programmer to set up sudo permissions for you?

Barring that, I still don't think your question is on-topic. It appears from the comment and current answer that it is not reproducible, your question requires more details. Either way, it has been reopened so I suppose I will not push that any further.